# what is java.net.IDN class in 1.6

Tags: java

what is java.net.IDN class in 1.6

Comment: The documentation seems fairly straightforward here... Is there something in particular that you're confused about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/IDN.html):

> Provides methods to convert internationalized domain names (IDNs) between a normal Unicode representation and an ASCII Compatible Encoding (ACE) representation.